# Jersey Client KeepAlive

Tags: java, jersey

Exactly what code fragment would I use to configure a vanilla Jersey Client instance to "keep-alive" connections? Thanks!

Comment: Please share some details. What are you trying to do? Why do you need to keep connections alive?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean HTTP keep-alives, it is supported by default and can be controlled by system properties.

Jersey client uses HttpURLConnection class internally, so http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html does apply for it as well.